# Prime Factorization Using Recursion

Tags: c++

My program currently outputs the prime factorization of a positive integer in ascending order. I'm trying to figure out how to set up the function so that it outputs the numbers in descending order.

For example, showFactors(100) currently outputs "2 2 5 5".

Instead I want it to output "5 5 2 2".

```
 10 // Void function "showFactors" that takes in an int "number" and another     int "factor", which is initialized to 2
 11 void showFactors(int number, int factor = 2)
 12 {
 13
 14   if (number<2) //returns nothing if number<2
 15   {
 16     return;
 17   }
 18   if (number%factor==0) //modulus function is used to get prime  factorization
 19   {
 20     cout<<factor<<" ";
 21     showFactors(number/factor, factor); //recursive call
 22   }
 23   else //if (number%factor != 0) //this modulus function is used in order to output factor !=2  
 24   {
 25     showFactors(number, factor+1);
 26   }
 27 }
```

I feel like there should be an easy fix by simply rearranging where the cout call goes, but I haven't had any luck so far.

Edit: Yeah it was as simple as switching lines 20 and 21.

Comment: @prp shouldn't it just go after line 21 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void sf (int number,int factor=2)
{
    if (number<2)
        return;
    if (number%factor == 0)
    {
        sf (number/factor,factor);
        cout<<factor<<"\t";
    }
    else
        sf (number,factor+1);
}

int main ()
{
    sf (1729);
    cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that was really simple, thanks. I had a misconception about recursion in that if the cout was placed after the recursive call, then the function would never get to call cout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Ruby solution to get a list of  prime factors of a given number. Maybe it will help someone

```rb
def prime_factorization(num)
    (2...num).each do |fact|
        if (num % fact == 0)
            otherFact = num / fact
            return [ *prime_factorization(fact), *prime_factorization(otherFact) ]
        end
    end

    return [num]
end
```